# How to use a thread to completion, then reuse the thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, wmi

I'm building a form and I'm trying to use threading in order to get some results from a WMI query to display in a textbox without having the form freeze up on the user. However, when I use the code below and use Break-All when debugging, the code just sits on `getPrinterThread.Join()`. I know I must be missing something.

My aim is to get a thread to run the ObtainPrinterPort method to completion, then get a thread to run the InstallPrinterPort method to completion. I have the code below as inline code in another method. The code isn't in a separate class or anything and I don't have a background worker because all of the examples I've seen, up until now, have only confused me.

Here's my admittedly poor thread attempt:

```
Thread printThread = new Thread(ObtainPrinterPort);
printThread.Start();
while (!printThread.IsAlive) ;
Thread.Sleep(1);
printThread.Join();         // Form sits and does nothing; Break-all reveals this line as statement being executed.

Thread installThread = new Thread(InstallPrinterPort);
installThread.Start();
while (!installThread.IsAlive);
Thread.Sleep(1);
installThread.Join();
```

Is there a simple way I can get something to work that is safe and will allow me to display the results that occur in the methods as they happen to the user in the textbox? Hopefully there's a way to do this that will allow me to continue to use the instance variables/methods/code I've written in the form class...otherwise, I'll have to re-write a lot of code if I'm going to implement a ["DoWork"-type example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (where my methods are called from the DoWork method/constructor or the Worker class).

**Please keep in mind that my methods need to return text from the thread to a textbox to display results to the user.** I have code that I'm assuming will allow me to return the text from the thread if it works, but I just wanted to make sure that any suggestions/help kept this in mind. The code I'm using is below:

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
        return;
    }

    txtResults.Text += value;
}
```

For what it's worth, here's my ObtainPrinterPort method and the CreateNewConnection method that accompanies it...the InstallPrinterPort method is extremely similar, so posting it won't really reveal much:

```
private ManagementScope CreateNewConnection(string server, string userID, string password)
{
    string serverString = @"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2";
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(serverString);

    try
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Username = userID,
            Password = password,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
            EnablePrivileges = true

        };
        scope.Options = options;
        scope.Connect();
    }
    catch (ManagementException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " +
                        err.Message);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection error (user name or password might be incorrect): " +                              unauthorizedErr.Message);
    }

    return scope;
}

private void ObtainPrinterPort()
{
    string computerName = "";
    string userID = "";
    string password = "";
    string printerQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = ";
    string portQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort WHERE Name = ";
    string search = "";
    SelectQuery query;

    foreach (var s in lstServer)
    {
        computerName = s.ServerName;
        userID = s.UserID;
        password = s.Password;
    }

    ManagementScope scope = CreateNewConnection(computerName, userID, password);

    foreach (Printers p in lstPrinters)
    {
        AppendTextBox("Obtaining printer/port info for " + p.PrinterName + "\r\n");

        search = printerQuery + "'" + p.PrinterName + "'";

        query = new SelectQuery(search);

        try
        {
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection printers = searcher.Get();

                if (printers.Count > 0)
                {
                    AppendTextBox("\tStoring printer properties for " + p.PrinterName + "\r\n");

                    foreach (ManagementObject mo in printers)
                    {
                        StorePrinterProperties(p, mo);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lstPrinterExceptions.Add("Printer: " + p.PrinterName);

                    AppendTextBox("\t**Printer " + p.PrinterName + " not found**\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exception.Message, "Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        if (!lstPrinterExceptions.Contains("Printer: " + p.PrinterName)
           && !lstPrinterExceptions.Contains("Port: " + p.PortName))
        {
            search = portQuery + "'" + p.PortName + "'";

            query = new SelectQuery(search);

            try
            {
                using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
                {
                    ManagementObjectCollection ports = searcher.Get();

                    if (ports.Count > 0)
                    {
                        AppendTextBox("\tStoring port properties for " + p.PortName + " (" + p.PrinterName + ")\r\n");

                        foreach (ManagementObject mo in ports)
                        {
                            StorePortProperties(p, mo);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstPrinterExceptions.Add("Port: " + p.PortName);

                        AppendTextBox("\t**Port " + p.PortName + " for " + p.PrinterName + " not found**\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exception.Message, "Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            AppendTextBox("\tSuccessfully obtained printer/port info for " + p.PrinterName + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post the contents of `ObtainPrinterPort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `Invoke` calls are blocking waiting for the main thread to `DoEvents` so they can be processed, but the main thread is blocking in `Thread.Join`. You have a deadlock.

This is how you run a thread without blocking the UI thread. `Thread.Join` blocks until the other thread finishes, so here I am blocking only for max 100ms, then calling `DoEvents` so the form can respond to messages (including processing your `Invoke` calls from the other thread), then looping until the background thread is complete.

```
Thread printThread = new Thread(ObtainPrinterPort);
printThread.Start();
while (printThread.IsAlive) {
    Application.DoEvents();        
    printThread.Join(100);        
}
```

Calling `DoEvents` in a loop like this is a bit hacky, but it will work.

You can also look into [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which makes the whole thing a lot safer and easier.

A simple example:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();            
bw.DoWork += (worker, args) => {
    ObtainPrinterPort();
};
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: @MartinJames please explain.

Comment: I cannot do so tonight - I'm pissed.  I am, however, sufficiently sober to recognise a really bad design.  BTW - not my downvote, though I think you deserve one.

Comment: Well, I'm certainly eager to hear your explanation when you sober up.

Comment: Will your example process my results as they occur or will I need to invoke the ProgressChanged class in order to update my textbox?

Comment: You can still `Invoke` from a backgroundworker, although using the ProgressChanged event is recommended.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think Martin and the downvoter were thinking about a cleaner approach like the `BackGroundWord`, +1 for it